# Slick proof the intersection of maximal ideals of a finitely generated domain is zero?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have seen in several places the result that taking polynomial rings preserves (and reflects) the Jacobson-Hilbert property, which is also preserved by quotients. Thus, in any finitely generated commutative ring, the nilradical equals the Jacobson radical. In particular, in a finitely generated domain, the intersection of all maximal ideals is zero.

I don't know commutative algebra, but I was wondering whether this result about zero intersection of maximal ideals can be proved "directly" for a finitely generated domain using Noether normalization. By 'directly' I mean 'without developing the theory of Jacobson rings'.

Comment: Do you object to slick direct proofs that don't use Noether normalization?

Comment: @EricWofsey never!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is quite what you're looking for, since it's really just a proof that a finitely generated algebra over a Jacobson ring is Jacobson, specialized to the case of $\mathbb{Z}$.  But here goes.  The key tool is the [Artin-Tate lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Tate_lemma) (you can use Noether normalization instead, but Artin-Tate gives what I would consider a more elementary argument).

First, let us prove that any field $K$ which is finitely generated as a ring is a finite field.  Let $k$ be the prime subfield of $K$.  Since $K$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra, it suffices to show $K$ has positive characteristic and is finite over $k$.  Let $B\subset K$ be a transcendence basis and note that $K$ is algebraic and hence finite over $k(B)$.  By the Artin-Tate lemma applied to the $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras $k(B)\subseteq K$, $k(B)$ is finitely generated as a ring.  This implies $B=\emptyset$ (any finitely generated subring of $k(B)$ has only finitely many irreducible polynomials which are factors of denominators of its elements, but there are infinitely many different irreducible polynomials in $k[B]$ if $B$ is nonempty).  Moreover, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a finitely generated ring, $k$ must have positive characteristic.  Thus $K$ is algebraic over $k=\mathbb{F}_p$ for some $p$ and hence is a finite field.

Now suppose $R$ is a finitely generated domain and $f\in R$ is nonzero.  The ring $S=R[f^{-1}]$ is then also a finitely generated domain, and so it has a maximal ideal $M$.  I claim that $M\cap R$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, and thus there exists a maximal ideal of $R$ which does not contain $f$.

To prove this, observe that field $S/M$ is finitely generated as a ring, and hence finite.  But $R/(M\cap R)$ is naturally a subring of $S/M$, and any subring of a finite field is a field.  Thus $R/(M\cap R)$ is a field, so $M\cap R$ is maximal.

Comment: In the final two paragraphs, the fact $R$ is a domain is what implies that localizations are injective, right?

Comment: Yes, although that's not essential (just replace $M\cap R$ with the inverse image of $M$ in $R$).

Comment: Is the injectivity not essential for the penultimate sentence to hold? Otherwise $R/(\iota ^\ast \mathfrak{m})$ need not be a subring of $S/\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: No, it's a subring no matter what.  The inverse image of $M$ is exactly the kernel of $R\to S\to S/M$.

Comment: So the assumption $R$ is a domain is superfluous? Otherwise where is it needed? I thought $R/(\iota ^\ast \mathfrak{m})$ injects into $S/\mathfrak m$ precisely because of the pullback stability of the mono $R\rightarrowtail S$ (which is a mono if $R$ is a domain).

Comment: The assumption that $R$ is a domain is needed to be sure that $S$ is a nonzero ring, so that it has a maximal ideal.  More generally, it would suffice to just assume that $f$ is not nilpotent, proving that the Jacobson radical of a finitely generated ring is the nilradical.